# Use of Either... or, or, and or in English

Tags: either-or

Can I say "A test comprises an equal number of items concerned with **either** prospective **or** retrospective, long-term **or** short-term, **and** self-cued **or** environmentally-cued memory subscales"?

Comment: Is this the same:  "A test comprises an equal number of items concerned with either prospective or retrospective memory subscales. The memory subscales can be long- or short- term, and self- or environmentally- cued"?

Comment: BTW... there seems to be an 'and' missing from the title of your question - it's confusing

Comment: Thank you for saying!

Yes it is the same. The thing that I want to point out is that each subscale is made up of half prospective and half retrospective memory items, half long- and half short- term memory items, and half self- and half environmentally- cued memory items.

Comment: You might be better off dropping *either* and changing all 3 instances of *or* to *and*. Otherwise there's some tension between *equal number* (i.e. all categories are represented) and the *exclusive or* interpretation (i.e. pick one but not both) suggested by the word *either*.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the context of options presented, I think you could slightly improve the clarity of what is meant in this sentence by inserting additional copies of "either":

> *A test comprises an equal number of items concerned with either prospective or retrospective,* **either** *long-term or short-term, and* **either** *self-cued or environmentally-cued memory subscales.*

But I think a much better option than trying to load more into that sentence is to lay out the options in several sentences or a bullet list. For example, if I understand correctly:

> A test comprises items concerned with various characteristics of memory subscales. These items should be equally split across:
>
> - prospective and retrospective
> - long-term and short-term
> - self-cued and environmentally-cued

Comment: +1 bullet points are a good idea but the example makes me think tests are split across 3 groups instead of drawing from each of the 3 groups.

Comment: Entirely possible, but that is really part of the point I am making (perhaps not clearly enough) that the meaning is being lost by trying to crunch this concept into one sentence.

Comment: Yes. Too big for 1 sentence...

Comment: I was agreeing, have now lent formal support ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your statement is technically wrong. It can be written generally like this:

> A Test comprises (something) with Either B1 or B2, C1 or C2 and D1 or
> D2

Which I interpret to mean that the test comprises something with:

- options from B and D, OR
- options from C and D

But not with options from B, C and D which is what I think you mean.

It might be more clear if you could say:

> A test comprises (something) with one of each of the following
> options/parameters: (B1 or B2), (C1 or C2) and (D1 or D2).

OR

> A test comprises (something) with one of each of the following
> options/parameters:
>
> - B1 or B2
> - C1 or C2
> - D1 or D2